# Getting full VHDL from Vivado

Tags: vhdl, vivado, spartan

Background: We have an FPGA that we are trying to use with third-party software (SciCompiler) that allows custom VHDL. This block of code must be included as plain text, not as a Vivado project or external files. The software allows us to use a 100 MHz clock, but a piece of code we are using requires an 80 MHz clock.

Our current attempt at a solution is to use the clocking wizard in Vivado (2023.1) to create an 80 MHz clock, export the resulting code, and paste it into the custom VHDL block in the third-party software. We have done this by creating a blank project, adding the clock wizard with the appropriate clock in and out, and then running “Generate Output Products“ in Out-of-Context mode. However, the only VHDL files we can find in Vivado are stubs – it doesn’t appear to output the full code needed for the clock adjustment, and in the third-party software, including only the stub does not compile, citing a generic syntax error near (.

So, how do (or can) we get the full VHDL code from a Vivado project?

An alternative possibility would be to answer: How do we generate VHDL code for Spartan-7 series that takes in 100 MHz clock and outputs 80 MHz clock?

Here is the stub we're working with:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity clk_wiz_0 is
  Port (
    clk_out1 : out STD_LOGIC;
    reset : in STD_LOGIC;
    locked : out STD_LOGIC;
    clk_in1 : in STD_LOGIC
  );

end clk_wiz_0;

architecture stub of clk_wiz_0 is
attribute syn_black_box : boolean;
attribute black_box_pad_pin : string;
attribute syn_black_box of stub : architecture is true;
attribute black_box_pad_pin of stub : architecture is "clk_out1,reset,locked,clk_in1";
begin
end;
```

Comment: This is likely implemented as vendor proprietary IP block or macro. You can't get VHDL code for it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yep.

Comment: Your FPGA must be on a some sort of board, no? Then why don't you simply use a 80MHz crystal oscillator to feed the design?

Comment: @Ale..chenski I don't control the design of the board. See this device: https://www.caen.it/products/sci-compiler-smart/